# Breakdown the error 0x800f081e returned from DISM

Tags: windows, windows-update

I want to learn how to breakdown an error such this one. I faced it by applying a Windows Update.

To be clear, I do not need someone to tell me what the meaning is:
I already looked for the error itself by googling and I know its meaning "CBS_E_NOT_APPLICABLE" ([link](https://serverfault.com/questions/655246/what-does-dism-return-code-0x800f081e-mean-when-installing-wmf-4-0-on-windows-7)).

I also looked in the DISM log; it states: "The package  is not applicable to the image." from the log line:

```
2024-02-15 13:02:43, Error                 DISM   API: PID=4804 TID=1852 The package  is not applicable to the image.  - CAddPackageCommandObject::InternalExecute(hr:0x800f081e)
```

So it is clear that the update is not applicable, in my case because a later Windows Cumulative Update has already been installed.

What I want is a method to breakdown an error and translate it to a human understandable meaning.

I already looked at the HRESULT error code structure ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a) and [here](https://nolongerset.com/breaking-down-windows-error-codes/).
I also understood that the "facility" part of the code is 15, that is "Setup API".

What I am not able to decode is the "Code" part, the two bytes on the right of the code that in my case is valued at 0x081e.

How can i get to that "CBS_E_NOT_APPLICABLE" error description?
I tried to Google for "setup api" error codes, I looked into the MS-ERREF reference... I did not found any result for that "81e" code.

Comment: The reason why I got -1 score on this question? It took several hours of reasearch before posting here. I wrote all the research I did. What more could I have done? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use err.exe, the [Error Lookup Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-code-lookup-tool). It'll break any hex or decimal error code, hex with or without the 0x, into the separate parts and tell you which header file it's defined in:

```
C:\Windows>err 800f081e
# for hex 0x800f081e / decimal -2146498530
  CBS_E_NOT_APPLICABLE                                           cbsapi.h
# the package is not applicable
# 1 matches found for "800f081e"
```

So in this case you're looking for cbsapi.h in one of the Windows SDKs which is where the 0x81e is defined. That's not a header I have to hand though.

As discussed below it looks like Microsoft have removed the cbsapi.h header from err.exe's index  The version I used is dated 2010. It appears to be an internal-only API now, although then it's a bug that Windows Installer is returning internal-only error codes.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Rup. I had already tried that tool but it says:    `C:\Windows>Err_6.4.5.exe 800f081e
# No results found for hex 0x800f081e / decimal -2146498530
# NOT FOUND: 800f081e`

Comment: Huh. I’ll double check but I’m reasonably sure I used 6.4.5 and it worked with the output I quoted.

Comment: could it be due to some ".h" header files that you have and not me? I tried: renaming the exe to err.exe; running the tool from a server with english OS; running from c:\windows... No luck. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you're right: I was actually running a really old err.exe "Last compiled on Apr 15 2010 12:00:59" which did have cbsapi.h in the list of compiled in headers, which 6.4.5 doesn't. [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039426/243245) say that even back then you weren't supposed to use CBS directly, so no idea why we're still getting its error codes. Sorry this isn't any help after all: I guess cbsapi is definitely no longer available.